# how to resolve StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am getting StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar exception but unable to identify

MyMain.java

```
public class MyMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");

        ReportDao dao=(ReportDao)ctx.getBean("edao");  

        List<Report> aList=dao.getJobDetails();
        Report obj=null;

        Iterator iterator = aList.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            obj = (Report) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(obj);
        }

    }
}
```

ReportDao.java

```
public class ReportDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1;

    public void setJdbcTemplate1(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate1 = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    private final String sql_select_schedular_job_details = "SELECT 'SCHEDULE_TYPE',SCHEDULED_DATE,'EMAIL_IDS',LAST_RUN_DATE  FROM PIL_GUI_QUARTZ_REPORTS ";

    private String qry="select 1 from dual";

    public List<Report> getJobDetails() {
        List<Report> reportList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            reportList = jdbcTemplate1.query(sql_select_schedular_job_details, new ReportMapper());
            //System.out.println(jdbcTemplate1.query(qry, new DemoMapper()));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return reportList;
    }

}
```

ReportMapper.java

```
public class ReportMapper implements RowMapper<Report>{

    public Report mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        Report report = new Report();
        report.setScheduledType(rs.getString("SCHEDULE_TYPE"));
        report.setScheduledDate(rs.getDate("SCHEDULED_DATE"));
        report.setEmailIds(rs.getString("EMAIL_IDS"));
        report.setLastRundDate(rs.getDate("LAST_RUN_DATE"));

        return report;
    }

}
```

Report.java

```
public class Report {

    private String scheduledType;
    private Date scheduledDate;
    private String emailIds;
    private Date lastRundDate;

    public String getScheduledType() {
        return scheduledType;
    }

    public void setScheduledType(String scheduledType) {
        this.scheduledType = scheduledType;
    }

    public Date getScheduledDate() {
        return scheduledDate;
    }

    public void setScheduledDate(Date scheduledDate) {
        this.scheduledDate = scheduledDate;
    }

    public String getEmailIds() {
        return emailIds;
    }

    public void setEmailIds(String emailIds) {
        this.emailIds = emailIds;
    }

    public Date getLastRundDate() {
        return lastRundDate;
    }

    public void setLastRundDate(Date lastRundDate) {
        this.lastRundDate = lastRundDate;
    }

}
```

Even if I have copied all the field names from DB and follow the same sequence in the mapper as the query but still getting exception, unable to know why. I query the same from SqlDeveloper and I am getting output. I tried with single_quote and without it also. This is a duplicate question but I am surprised why it is not working even the query is very simple, only a select statement. The table is inside synonym and the table name and the synonym name both are same.

StackTrace

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [  SELECT 'SCHEDULE_TYPE', SCHEDULED_DATE , 'EMAIL_IDS', LAST_RUN_DATE  FROM PIL_GUI_QUARTZ_REPORTS ]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:419)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:474)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:484)
    at com.myapp.dao.ReportDao.getJobDetails(ReportDao.java:30)
    at com.myapp.main.MyMain.main(MyMain.java:19)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:202)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:45)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:766)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1034)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1244)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:420)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:458)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:408)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about, I didn't post an answer. In any case, the error suggest that the table doesn't exist in your default schema. Either connect with the right user, or specify the schema explicitly.

Comment: It is connected to the schema, because if you see the sop statement in my DAO class then it is returning me object(from dual) without throwing exception.